# C++ undefined reference with static library

Tags: c++, reference, static, undefined

I got 'undefined reference' when compile code with a static library. I have searched a lot of answer which told to use extern "C" or correct the order of parameter when compiling, but those doesn't solve my problem.
I have these :

compiler.hpp

```
#ifndef COMPILER_H
#define COMPILER_H

int buildTree();

#endif
```

compile.cpp

```
#include <compiler.hpp>

int buildTree() {

     Package package = new Package();

}
```

And a lot of another source code, then I build them to lib.a by building them into .o files with -c flag and :

```
ar rvs lib.a $(OBJS)
```

My Main.cpp:

```
#include <compiler.hpp>

int main() {

     buildTree();

}
```

Finally, I build executable file :

```
LIBS = lib.a

main: main.cpp
$(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LIBDIR) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@
```

But g++ complier throws this Error :

```
undefined reference to `buildTree()'
```

Comment: Inside your `buildTree` function shouldn't you have a pointer to a Package? So shouldn't you do this `Package *package = new Package();`? I mean the way you wrote the code it won't compile. I'm not sure if this is the issue you're having, but that's worth checking.

Comment: `main: main.cpp lib.a`, that's it, you don't event need the recipe because the executable name matches the source stem.

Comment: After fixing your syntax errors, your example works flawlessly for me (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, g++ 4.8.4). Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** example that demonstrates your error. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: I tried to remove that line, but still not working :(

Comment: Try extern int buildTree(); in hpp

Comment: but package is not a keyword in c++ :)

Comment: I forgot implement compile.o to lib.a, lol